# AnkhSVN shelves

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, ankhsvn

I just setup AnkhSVN after having used TFS till now

What in AnkhSVN is the equivalent of shelves that I would create/use in TFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest equivalent to shelving in Subversion is to create a branch and switch to it, commit your "work in progress", then switch back to the trunk. Later on you can merge from that "shelf branch" to get back to where you were. When evaluating TFS and Subversion before using either of them in anger I expected shelving to be really handy and an ability I'd miss in Subversion - but I've found that branching and switching is so simple in Subversion, it's actually quicker than using shelves anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Subversion does not currently have a feature equivalent to shelving changes in TFS.

Your best bet would be to create multiple concurrent branches for different features and merge the branches back into your trunk when the associated feature/changes are complete.

The following blog post has a lot of information on how to do this: http://markphip.blogspot.com/2007/01/shelves-in-subversion.html